# Spectrum of the adjacency matrix of certain directed graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

For an undirected graph $G$, its adjacency matrix $A_G$ is symmetric, and by the (consequence of) spectral theorem, each of its Jordan blocks has size $1$. This is not true for a general directed graph, except for certain special cases like the directed cycle graphs.

Question: Suppose in a directed graph $G$, each edge is contained in a cycle (e.g., undirected graphs, directed cycle graphs). Is it true that each Jordan block of $A_G$ has size $1$?

Answer (score 2):

It is not true.  Take the digraph with adjacency matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0& 1 &0& 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1& 0\\ 0 & 1& 0 &1\\ 1 & 0 &0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$  This digraph is strongly connected (so every edge is contained in a cycle).  The eigenvalues are $0,0,\pm\sqrt{2}$ and the Jordan block of $0$ is $2\times 2$.

Comment: Thank you for the example.